# Как реализовать фото товара и его превью?

Tags: html, css

Верстаю макет интернет-магазина, в товаре есть фото товара и его вариации (превью).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос, это задача верстальщика или того, кто будет натягивать шаблон на движок?
Если это задача верстальщика, то как лучше реализовать это?

Comment: Я бы сказал это работа того, кто будет заполнять базу товарами. А программист должен обеспечить для него удобную работу, т.е. что бы он тупо заливал фото к товару, а программа уже сама генерит из него картинки нужных размеров и выводит где задумано

Comment: Все оформление, работа превью товара, калькулятор - это верстальщик. А вот уже обработка заказа - это уже back-end.

Comment: Я так понимаю, щелкая по миниатюре фото, она должна отображаться в основном окне. Как это реализовать?

Comment: выводи модальное окно, с нужным размером фотки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это работа верстака на все 100%. 
По простому без плагинов на чистом js примерно так:

```js
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('#thumbs > a');
var big = document.getElementById('big');

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        big.src = this.href;
    });
}
```

```css
#big { width: 300px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block }

#thumbs a { display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
#thumbs a img { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//c4.staticflickr.com/9/8348/28914145963_11390118bf_k.jpg" id="big">
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
  <a href="//c4.staticflickr.com/9/8348/28914145963_11390118bf_k.jpg">
    <img src="//c4.staticflickr.com/9/8348/28914145963_487a628204_t.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="//c5.staticflickr.com/9/8138/29253663020_bd1cfa9588_h.jpg">
    <img src="//c5.staticflickr.com/9/8138/29253663020_ac9d8fc85a_m.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="//c6.staticflickr.com/8/7744/29465490141_87d5236c24_b.jpg">
    <img src="//c6.staticflickr.com/8/7744/29465490141_87d5236c24_t.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Для большей кроссбраузерности можно использовать jQuery; Или вообще плагин для этого найти.

Comment: Лучше добавить background-image и заливать фотки в него. Тогда картинка не будет менять размер. И задать bacground-size: cover. Это примечание если кто воспользуется этим скриптом :)

Comment: @Levelleor совсем несогласен. Если нужно отцентровать картинку есть другие способы, например `transform translate` с `position absolute`; ну ну крайняк `table-cell`; В вашем комментарии вы лишитесь отслеживать статус загрузки изображения и зарежете возможно полезные края картинки.

Comment: Ну можно использовать contain. Отслеживать загрузку картинки можно скриптом. Нужно контролировать размер блока с картинкой что бы дизайн не рухнул. В конце концов когда главная картинка меняет размер получается очень неудобная навигация.

Comment: Кстати а Transform translate может испортить качество изображения и размыть его, так что его тоже крайне не рекомендую использовать. Если уж так то только table-cell...

Comment: Посмотрел бы как вы будете отслеживать загрузку `background-image`. ) Мне в голову приходит только `xhr` в `string` с конвертацией в `base64`, но такая садамия на любителя. Да, с трансформом может быть беда, есть такая тема.

Comment: А есть ли плагины какие-то? Или как можно это реализовать на jQuery?

Comment: я пользуюсь этим: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ; там вроде можно по простому сделать вашу задачу, но я делал 2 синхронизированные галереи и писал к нему отдельно зум: https://brandshop.ru/goods/18267/krossovki-asics-gel-lyte-v-lavender-purple-beige/